# Why is it that I cannot run or debug html on safari

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I am new and learning html using VsCode on Mac, I have written my first html code but before I could run, I was given only two options, chrome and Edge, why is it that I cannot run it on safari

Answer (score 0):

You can open your html file in Safari. Just right click on it and choose "open with Safari". Or second solution, you open safari and you drag your file in.
Nevertheless, it is recommended to use Chrome or Firefox to do debugging. You can also use Brave which is great !

Comment: That is not an answer, I also want to know the real answer, how to run and debug on Safari. Not everyone has drunk the Chrome Kool-aid. 

I can't imagine there is no way to configure your own run and preview?

Comment: Calm down... But if you want a more precise answer, please tell me what you use to run it. do you double-click it? do you open it with it? do you drag it into the browser? If not, how do you give a precise answer? If nobody else has answered, there must be a reason...

But one of the solutions for debugging on Safari is :
launch Safari, go to settings, advanced, and check "Show Development Menu" in the menu bar.
After that you have access to all the debug tool in Safari

Comment: What I am looking for would be how do we add option to run the app and launch the browser from the menu. 

I couldn't find out how to do this yet with a custom run action (which I expected to be available).

Sorry for the off cuff response but read way too many "just use Chrome comments that day". :)